# Continuity of complex difference quotient

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, holomorphic-functions

In my complex analysis course the professor used the folowing fact: If $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open and $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function (we defined this as $f$ being differentiable and its derivative being continuous) then the function $g: U^2 \to \mathbb{C}$

$
g(z, c) = \begin{cases} 
          \frac{f(z) - f(c)}{z - c} & z \neq c \\
          f'(c) & z = c
           \end{cases}
$

is continuous.

I can prove this by using the fact that $f$ is equal to a power series but I would like to see a proof that doesn't use this since we haven't proved it in my course.

Comment: Typically we fix $c$ and show $g$ is a continuous function of $z$, and I suspect _this_ is the fact your professor used?

Comment: @B.Mehta no, the proof depended on $g$ being a continuous function of $c$ _and_ $z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressing $f(z)$, $f(c)$ and $f'(c)$ by the Cauchy integral formula, you find
$$ g(z,c)=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)(\zeta-c)} $$
where $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve surrounding $z$ and $c$.
This is clearly continuous.

Comment: we used the original function to proove Cauchy's integral theorem. I suppose proving the continuity using the integral formula would be circular reasoning then...

Comment: Yes, unless the proof used only the the *separate* continuity of $g$? You may notice that the joint continuity of $g$ implies the continuity of $f'$. That already tells you that it's not some trivial calculation, as the corresponding statement is false for real differentiable functions. To expand a little on this, I think it is nearly impossible to answer your question without knowing more about the approach used by your professor in this course. It rings a bell – I have seen something similar – but there isn't enough to go on.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen With the real case you mean a $C^1$ function on $R^2$ (so where the separate case is also true)? Can you provide an example where the joint case fails?

Comment: @SebastianBechtel I *think* what I had in mind is a differentiable function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Define $g\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ as in the question: Then $g$ is separately continuous. However, if $f'$ is not continuous, then $g$ is not (joint) continuous either. A simple example is $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$.